# Combine multiple queries into single query

Tags: oracle, plsql

I am trying to run the following query:

```
SELECT Freight.Freight_No,
       Freight.Available,
       Locomotive.Loco_No, 
       Locomotive.Available,
       Driver.Driver_No, 
       Driver.Name, 
       Driver.Available 
FROM Freight,Locomotive, Driver
WHERE Freight.Available = 'Y'
  AND Locomotive.Available = 'Y'
  AND Driver.Available = 'Y'
GROUP BY Freight.Freight_No, Locomotive.Loco_No, Driver.Driver_No;
```

What I am trying to do is check available freight wagons, locomotives and drivers. I can individually run a SELECT statements. However I want to combine into one query. I understand I can do this using `UNION` but I may not be going about it the correct way.

**Tables**

Freight

```
CREATE TABLE Freight
(
  Freight_No integer PRIMARY KEY, Serial_No integer UNIQUE, 
  Freight_Wagon_Type_Name varchar(20) 
    REFERENCES Freight_Wagon_Type(Freight_Wagon_Type_Name),
  Available varchar2(1) 
     CONSTRAINT AvailableFreight CHECK(Available IN('Y','N')) NOT NULL
);
```

Locomotive

```
CREATE TABLE Locomotive
(
  Loco_No integer PRIMARY KEY, 
  Serial_No integer UNIQUE, 
  Loco_Class_No integer 
    REFERENCES Locomotive_Class(Loco_Class_No), 
  Loco_name varchar2(20), 
  Available varchar2(1) 
     CONSTRAINT Available CHECK(Available IN('Y','N')) NOT NULL
);
```

Driver

```
CREATE TABLE Driver
(
   Driver_No integer PRIMARY KEY, 
   Name varchar2(20),
   Available varchar2(1) 
     CONSTRAINT AvailableDriver CHECK(Available IN('Y','N')) NOT NULL
);
```

Comment: Why the `group by` you are not aggregating? You are also missing join conditions (preferrably using using standard SQL 92 `JOIN`s)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use UNION [ALL] to combine rows from multiple queries, as long as the number of columns are the same and the columns are compatible, if not of the exact same types.

```
SELECT 'Driver' as SourceTable, Driver_No, Name, Available 
  FROM Driver
 WHERE Available = 'Y'
 UNION ALL
SELECT 'Freight', Freight_No, Freight_Wagon_Type_Name, Available
  FROM Freight
 WHERE Available = 'Y'
 UNION ALL
SELECT 'Locomotive', Loco_No, Loco_Name, Available
  FROM Locomotive
 WHERE Available = 'Y';
```

*(added **SourceTable** column per a_horse_with_no_name's suggestion)*

Note that the column names are taken from the first query in the UNION, which means you end up with `(SourceTable, Driver_No, Name, Available)`.  You can always alias them as required.

Comment: You might want to add a column that identifies the "source" of each row to be able to distinguish between driver, freight and locomotive.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name this is exactly what I am trying to do. How would I go about doing this?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name did it by using `'table1' as table_name`

Comment: i think that if you'll wrap the union with parenthesis and add the condition once in the end, oracle will push the predicate and you will have a much more maintainable code.